# Jquery.filer deletes the thumb but does not deselect from selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `jquery.filer` it works but when i delete the thumb it does but it is not deselecting the image from selection of images.

For Example I have selected 4 images and i deleted one of them (which deletes the thumb) and press upload or submit it is uploading all 4 (including the 1 i deleted) not 3.

I have tried to change different options like (onRemove, onEmpty) and others but im unable to get it work.

**Please Check New Updated jsFiddle With change in some code, check in jsFiddle**

[jsFiddle Updated - 002](https://jsfiddle.net/4swmLxay/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://gerardbalaoro.github.io/jQuery.filer/css/plugins/jquery.filer.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://gerardbalaoro.github.io/jQuery.filer/css/plugins/themes/jquery.filer-dragdropbox-theme.css">

<script src="https://gerardbalaoro.github.io/jQuery.filer/js/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<form id="new_post_form" name="foo" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="submit.php" target="pp_comments" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" class="docupload" name="file[]" >

<input type="submit" value="submits">
</form>
```

**custom.js**

```
<script>
    window.onload=function(){

 /*!
 * jQuery.filer minified
 * Copyright (c) 2016 CreativeDream
 * Website: https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.filer
 * Version: 1.3 (14-Sep-2016)
 * Requires: jQuery v1.7.1 or later
 */
!function(a){"use strict";a.fn.filer=function(b){return this.each(function(c,d){var e=a(d),f=".jFiler",g=a(),h=a(),i=a(),j=[],k=a.isFunction(b)?b(e,a.fn.filer.defaults):b,l=k&&a.isPlainObject(k)?a.extend(!0,{},a.fn.filer.defaults,k):a.fn.filer.defaults,m={init:function(){e.wrap('<div class="jFiler"></div>'),m._set("props"),e.prop("jFiler").boxEl=g=e.closest(f),m._changeInput()},_bindInput:function(){l.changeInput&&h.length>0&&h.on("click",m._clickHandler),e.on({focus:function(){h.addClass("focused")},blur:function(){h.removeClass("focused")},change:m._onChange}),l.dragDrop&&(l.dragDrop.dragContainer.on("drag dragstart dragend dragover dragenter dragleave drop",function(a){a.preventDefault(),a.stopPropagation()}),l.dragDrop.dragContainer.on("drop",m._dragDrop.drop),l.dragDrop.dragContainer.on("dragover",m._dragDrop.dragEnter),l.dragDrop.dragContainer.on("dragleave",m._dragDrop.dragLeave)),l.uploadFile&&l.clipBoardPaste&&a(window).on("paste",m._clipboardPaste)},_unbindInput:function(b){l.changeInput&&h.length>0&&h.off("click",m._clickHandler),b&&(e.off("change",m._onChange),l.dragDrop&&(l.dragDrop.dragContainer.off("drop",m._dragDrop.drop),l.dragDrop.dragContainer.off("dragover",m._dragDrop.dragEnter),l.dragDrop.dragContainer.off("dragleave",m._dragDrop.dragLeave)),l.uploadFile&&l.clipBoardPaste&&a(window).off("paste",m._clipboardPaste))},_clickHandler:function(){if(!l.uploadFile&&l.addMore&&0!=e.val().length){m._unbindInput(!0);var b=a('<input type="file" />'),c=e.prop("attributes");a.each(c,function(){"required"!=this.name&&b.attr(this.name,this.value)}),e.after(b),j.push(b),e=b,m._bindInput(),m._set("props")}e.click()},_applyAttrSettings:function(){var a=["name","limit","maxSize","fileMaxSize","extensions","changeInput","showThumbs","appendTo","theme","addMore","excludeName","files","uploadUrl","uploadData","options"];for(var b in a){var c="data-jfiler-"+a[b];if(m._assets.hasAttr(c)){switch(a[b]){case"changeInput":case"showThumbs":case"addMore":l[a[b]]=["true","false"].indexOf(e.attr(c))>-1?"true"==e.attr(c):e.attr(c);break;case"extensions":l[a[b]]=e.attr(c).replace(/ /g,"").split(",");break;case"uploadUrl":l.uploadFile&&(l.uploadFile.url=e.attr(c));break;case"uploadData":l.uploadFile&&(l.uploadFile.data=JSON.parse(e.attr(c)));break;case"files":case"options":l[a[b]]=JSON.parse(e.attr(c));break;default:l[a[b]]=e.attr(c)}e.removeAttr(c)}}},_changeInput:function(){if(m._applyAttrSettings(),null!=l.beforeRender&&"function"==typeof l.beforeRender?l.beforeRender(g,e):null,l.theme&&g.addClass("jFiler-theme-"+l.theme),"input"!=e.get(0).tagName.toLowerCase()&&"file"!=e.get(0).type)h=e,e=a('<input type="file" name="'+l.name+'" />'),e.css({position:"absolute",left:"-9999px",top:"-9999px","z-index":"-9999"}),g.prepend(e),m._isGn=e;else if(l.changeInput){switch(typeof l.changeInput){case"boolean":h=a('<div class="jFiler-input"><div class="jFiler-input-caption"><span>'+l.captions.feedback+'</span></div><div class="jFiler-input-button">'+l.captions.button+'</div></div>"');break;case"string":case"object":h=a(l.changeInput);break;case"function":h=a(l.changeInput(g,e,l))}e.after(h),e.css({position:"absolute",left:"-9999px",top:"-9999px","z-index":"-9999"})}e.prop("jFiler").newInputEl=h,l.dragDrop&&(l.dragDrop.dragContainer=l.dragDrop.dragContainer?a(l.dragDrop.dragContainer):h),(!l.limit||l.limit&&l.limit>=2)&&(e.attr("multiple","multiple"),"[]"!=e.attr("name").slice(-2)?e.attr("name",e.attr("name")+"[]"):null),e.attr("disabled")||l.disabled?(l.disabled=!0,m._unbindInput(!0),g.addClass("jFiler-disabled")):(l.disabled=!1,m._bindInput(),g.removeClass("jFiler-disabled")),l.files&&m._append(!1,{files:l.files}),null!=l.afterRender&&"function"==typeof l.afterRender?l.afterRender(i,g,h,e):null},_clear:function(){m.files=null,e.prop("jFiler").files=null,l.uploadFile||l.addMore||m._reset(),m._set("feedback",m._itFl&&m._itFl.length>0?m._itFl.length+" "+l.captions.feedback2:l.captions.feedback),null!=l.onEmpty&&"function"==typeof l.onEmpty?l.onEmpty(g,h,e):null},_reset:function(b){if(!b){if(!l.uploadFile&&l.addMore){for(var c=0;c<j.length;c++)j[c].remove();j=[],m._unbindInput(!0),e=m._isGn?m._isGn:a(d),m._bindInput()}m._set("input","")}m._itFl=[],m._itFc=null,m._ajFc=0,m._set("props"),e.prop("jFiler").files_list=m._itFl,e.prop("jFiler").current_file=m._itFc,m._itFr=[],g.find("input[name^='jfiler-items-exclude-']:hidden").remove(),i.fadeOut("fast",function(){a(this).remove()}),e.prop("jFiler").listEl=i=a()},_set:function(a,b){switch(a){case"input":e.val(b);break;case"feedback":h.length>0&&h.find(".jFiler-input-caption span").html(b);break;case"props":e.prop("jFiler")||e.prop("jFiler",{options:l,listEl:i,boxEl:g,newInputEl:h,inputEl:e,files:m.files,files_list:m._itFl,current_file:m._itFc,append:function(a){return m._append(!1,{files:[a]})},enable:function(){l.disabled&&(l.disabled=!1,e.removeAttr("disabled"),g.removeClass("jFiler-disabled"),m._bindInput())},disable:function(){l.disabled||(l.disabled=!0,g.addClass("jFiler-disabled"),m._unbindInput(!0))},remove:function(a){return m._remove(null,{binded:!0,data:{id:a}}),!0},reset:function(){return m._reset(),m._clear(),!0},retry:function(a){return m._retryUpload(a)}})}},_filesCheck:function(){var b=0;if(l.limit&&m.files.length+m._itFl.length>l.limit)return l.dialogs.alert(m._assets.textParse(l.captions.errors.filesLimit)),!1;for(var c=0;c<m.files.length;c++){var d=m.files[c],e=d.name.split(".").pop().toLowerCase(),f={name:d.name,size:d.size,size2:m._assets.bytesToSize(d.size),type:d.type,ext:e};if(null!=l.extensions&&a.inArray(e,l.extensions)==-1&&a.inArray(f.type,l.extensions)==-1)return l.dialogs.alert(m._assets.textParse(l.captions.errors.filesType,f)),!1;if(null!=l.maxSize&&m.files[c].size>1048576*l.maxSize||null!=l.fileMaxSize&&m.files[c].size>1048576*l.fileMaxSize)return l.dialogs.alert(m._assets.textParse(l.captions.errors.filesSize,f)),!1;if(4096==d.size&&0==d.type.length)return l.dialogs.alert(m._assets.textParse(l.captions.errors.folderUpload,f)),!1;if(null!=l.onFileCheck&&"function"==typeof l.onFileCheck?l.onFileCheck(f,l,m._assets.textParse)===!1:null)return!1;if((l.uploadFile||l.addMore)&&!l.allowDuplicates){var f=m._itFl.filter(function(a,b){if(a.file.name==d.name&&a.file.size==d.size&&a.file.type==d.type&&(!d.lastModified||a.file.lastModified==d.lastModified))return!0});if(f.length>0){if(1==m.files.length)return!1;d._pendRemove=!0}}b+=m.files[c].size}return!(null!=l.maxSize&&b>=Math.round(1048576*l.maxSize))||(l.dialogs.alert(m._assets.textParse(l.captions.errors.filesSizeAll)),!1)},_thumbCreator:{create:function(b){var c=m.files[b],d=m._itFc?m._itFc.id:b,e=c.name,f=c.size,g=c.file,h=c.type?c.type.split("/",1):"".toString().toLowerCase(),j=e.indexOf(".")!=-1?e.split(".").pop().toLowerCase():"",k=l.uploadFile?'<div class="jFiler-jProgressBar">'+l.templates.progressBar+"</div>":"",n={id:d,name:e,size:f,size2:m._assets.bytesToSize(f),url:g,type:h,extension:j,icon:m._assets.getIcon(j,h),icon2:m._thumbCreator.generateIcon({type:h,extension:j}),image:'<div class="jFiler-item-thumb-image fi-loading"></div>',progressBar:k,_appended:c._appended},o="";return c.opts&&(n=a.extend({},c.opts,n)),o=a(m._thumbCreator.renderContent(n)).attr("data-jfiler-index",d),o.get(0).jfiler_id=d,m._thumbCreator.renderFile(c,o,n),c.forList?o:(m._itFc.html=o,o.hide()[l.templates.itemAppendToEnd?"appendTo":"prependTo"](i.find(l.templates._selectors.list)).show(),void(c._appended||m._onSelect(b)))},renderContent:function(a){return m._assets.textParse(a._appended?l.templates.itemAppend:l.templates.item,a)},renderFile:function(b,c,d){if(0==c.find(".jFiler-item-thumb-image").length)return!1;if(b.file&&"image"==d.type){var e='<img src="'+b.file+'" draggable="false" />',f=c.find(".jFiler-item-thumb-image.fi-loading");return a(e).error(function(){e=m._thumbCreator.generateIcon(d),c.addClass("jFiler-no-thumbnail"),f.removeClass("fi-loading").html(e)}).load(function(){f.removeClass("fi-loading").html(e)}),!0}if(window.File&&window.FileList&&window.FileReader&&"image"==d.type&&d.size<1e7){var g=new FileReader;g.onload=function(a){var b=c.find(".jFiler-item-thumb-image.fi-loading");if(l.templates.canvasImage){var e=document.createElement("canvas"),f=e.getContext("2d"),g=new Image;g.onload=function(){var a=b.height(),c=b.width(),d=g.height/a,h=g.width/c,i=d<h?d:h,j=g.height/i,k=g.width/i,l=Math.ceil(Math.log(g.width/k)/Math.log(2));if(e.height=a,e.width=c,g.width<e.width||g.height<e.height||l<=1){var m=g.width<e.width?e.width/2-g.width/2:g.width>e.width?-(g.width-e.width)/2:0,n=g.height<e.height?e.height/2-g.height/2:0;f.drawImage(g,m,n,g.width,g.height)}else{var o=document.createElement("canvas"),p=o.getContext("2d");o.width=.5*g.width,o.height=.5*g.height,p.fillStyle="#fff",p.fillRect(0,0,o.width,o.height),p.drawImage(g,0,0,o.width,o.height),p.drawImage(o,0,0,.5*o.width,.5*o.height),f.drawImage(o,k>e.width?k-e.width:0,0,.5*o.width,.5*o.height,0,0,k,j)}b.removeClass("fi-loading").html('<img src="'+e.toDataURL("image/png")+'" draggable="false" />')},g.onerror=function(){c.addClass("jFiler-no-thumbnail"),b.removeClass("fi-loading").html(m._thumbCreator.generateIcon(d))},g.src=a.target.result}else b.removeClass("fi-loading").html('<img src="'+a.target.result+'" draggable="false" />')},g.readAsDataURL(b)}else{var e=m._thumbCreator.generateIcon(d),f=c.find(".jFiler-item-thumb-image.fi-loading");c.addClass("jFiler-no-thumbnail"),f.removeClass("fi-loading").html(e)}},generateIcon:function(b){var c=new Array(3);if(b&&b.type&&b.type[0]&&b.extension)switch(b.type[0]){case"image":c[0]="f-image",c[1]='<i class="icon-jfi-file-image"></i>';break;case"video":c[0]="f-video",c[1]='<i class="icon-jfi-file-video"></i>';break;case"audio":c[0]="f-audio",c[1]='<i class="icon-jfi-file-audio"></i>';break;default:c[0]="f-file f-file-ext-"+b.extension,c[1]=b.extension.length>0?"."+b.extension:"",c[2]=1}else c[0]="f-file",c[1]=b.extension&&b.extension.length>0?"."+b.extension:"",c[2]=1;var d='<span class="jFiler-icon-file '+c[0]+'">'+c[1]+"</span>";if(1==c[2]){var e=m._assets.text2Color(b.extension);if(e){var f=a(d).appendTo("body");f.css("background-color",m._assets.text2Color(b.extension)),d=f.prop("outerHTML"),f.remove()}}return d},_box:function(b){if(null!=l.beforeShow&&"function"==typeof l.beforeShow&&!l.beforeShow(m.files,i,g,h,e))return!1;if(i.length<1){if(l.appendTo)var c=a(l.appendTo);else var c=g;c.find(".jFiler-items").remove(),i=a('<div class="jFiler-items jFiler-row"></div>'),e.prop("jFiler").listEl=i,i.append(m._assets.textParse(l.templates.box)).appendTo(c),i.on("click",l.templates._selectors.remove,function(c){c.preventDefault();var d=[b?b.remove.event:c,b?b.remove.el:a(this).closest(l.templates._selectors.item)],e=function(a){m._remove(d[0],d[1])};l.templates.removeConfirmation?l.dialogs.confirm(l.captions.removeConfirmation,e):e()})}for(var d=0;d<m.files.length;d++)m.files[d]._appended||(m.files[d]._choosed=!0),m._addToMemory(d),m._thumbCreator.create(d)}},_upload:function(b){var c=m._itFl[b],d=c.html,f=new FormData;if(f.append(e.attr("name"),c.file,!!c.file.name&&c.file.name),null!=l.uploadFile.data&&a.isPlainObject("function"==typeof l.uploadFile.data?l.uploadFile.data(c.file):l.uploadFile.data))for(var g in l.uploadFile.data)f.append(g,l.uploadFile.data[g]);m._ajax.send(d,f,c)},_ajax:{send:function(b,c,d){return d.ajax=a.ajax({url:l.uploadFile.url,data:c,type:l.uploadFile.type,enctype:l.uploadFile.enctype,xhr:function(){var c=a.ajaxSettings.xhr();return c.upload&&c.upload.addEventListener("progress",function(a){m._ajax.progressHandling(a,b)},!1),c},complete:function(a,b){d.ajax=!1,m._ajFc++,l.uploadFile.synchron&&d.id+1<m._itFl.length&&m._upload(d.id+1),m._ajFc>=m.files.length&&(m._ajFc=0,e.get(0).value="",null!=l.uploadFile.onComplete&&"function"==typeof l.uploadFile.onComplete?l.uploadFile.onComplete(i,g,h,e,a,b):null)},beforeSend:function(a,c){return null==l.uploadFile.beforeSend||"function"!=typeof l.uploadFile.beforeSend||l.uploadFile.beforeSend(b,i,g,h,e,d.id,a,c)},success:function(a,c,f){d.uploaded=!0,null!=l.uploadFile.success&&"function"==typeof l.uploadFile.success?l.uploadFile.success(a,b,i,g,h,e,d.id,c,f):null},error:function(a,c,f){d.uploaded=!1,null!=l.uploadFile.error&&"function"==typeof l.uploadFile.error?l.uploadFile.error(b,i,g,h,e,d.id,a,c,f):null},statusCode:l.uploadFile.statusCode,cache:!1,contentType:!1,processData:!1}),d.ajax},progressHandling:function(a,b){if(a.lengthComputable){var c=Math.round(100*a.loaded/a.total).toString();null!=l.uploadFile.onProgress&&"function"==typeof l.uploadFile.onProgress?l.uploadFile.onProgress(c,b,i,g,h,e):null,b.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").find(l.templates._selectors.progressBar).css("width",c+"%")}}},_dragDrop:{dragEnter:function(a){clearTimeout(m._dragDrop._drt),l.dragDrop.dragContainer.addClass("dragged"),m._set("feedback",l.captions.drop),null!=l.dragDrop.dragEnter&&"function"==typeof l.dragDrop.dragEnter?l.dragDrop.dragEnter(a,h,e,g):null},dragLeave:function(a){clearTimeout(m._dragDrop._drt),m._dragDrop._drt=setTimeout(function(a){return m._dragDrop._dragLeaveCheck(a)?(l.dragDrop.dragContainer.removeClass("dragged"),m._set("feedback",l.captions.feedback),void(null!=l.dragDrop.dragLeave&&"function"==typeof l.dragDrop.dragLeave?l.dragDrop.dragLeave(a,h,e,g):null)):(m._dragDrop.dragLeave(a),!1)},100,a)},drop:function(a){clearTimeout(m._dragDrop._drt),l.dragDrop.dragContainer.removeClass("dragged"),m._set("feedback",l.captions.feedback),a&&a.originalEvent&&a.originalEvent.dataTransfer&&a.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files&&a.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length>0&&m._onChange(a,a.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files),null!=l.dragDrop.drop&&"function"==typeof l.dragDrop.drop?l.dragDrop.drop(a.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files,a,h,e,g):null},_dragLeaveCheck:function(b){var c=a(b.currentTarget),d=0;return!(!c.is(h)&&(d=h.find(c).length,d>0))}},_clipboardPaste:function(a,b){if((b||a.originalEvent.clipboardData||a.originalEvent.clipboardData.items)&&(!b||a.originalEvent.dataTransfer||a.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items)&&!m._clPsePre){var c=b?a.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items:a.originalEvent.clipboardData.items,d=function(a,b,c){b=b||"",c=c||512;for(var d=atob(a),e=[],f=0;f<d.length;f+=c){for(var g=d.slice(f,f+c),h=new Array(g.length),i=0;i<g.length;i++)h[i]=g.charCodeAt(i);var j=new Uint8Array(h);e.push(j)}var k=new Blob(e,{type:b});return k};if(c)for(var e=0;e<c.length;e++)if(c[e].type.indexOf("image")!==-1||c[e].type.indexOf("text/uri-list")!==-1){if(b)try{window.atob(a.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/uri-list").toString().split(",")[1])}catch(a){return}var f=b?d(a.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/uri-list").toString().split(",")[1],"image/png"):c[e].getAsFile();f.name=Math.random().toString(36).substring(5),f.name+=f.type.indexOf("/")!=-1?"."+f.type.split("/")[1].toString().toLowerCase():".png",m._onChange(a,[f]),m._clPsePre=setTimeout(function(){delete m._clPsePre},1e3)}}},_onSelect:function(b){l.uploadFile&&!a.isEmptyObject(l.uploadFile)&&(!l.uploadFile.synchron||l.uploadFile.synchron&&0==a.grep(m._itFl,function(a){return a.ajax}).length)&&m._upload(m._itFc.id),m.files[b]._pendRemove&&(m._itFc.html.hide(),m._remove(null,{binded:!0,data:{id:m._itFc.id}})),null!=l.onSelect&&"function"==typeof l.onSelect?l.onSelect(m.files[b],m._itFc.html,i,g,h,e):null,b+1>=m.files.length&&(null!=l.afterShow&&"function"==typeof l.afterShow?l.afterShow(i,g,h,e):null)},_onChange:function(b,c){if(c){if(!c||0==c.length)return m._set("input",""),m._clear(),!1;m.files=c}else{if(!e.get(0).files||"undefined"==typeof e.get(0).files||0==e.get(0).files.length)return l.uploadFile||l.addMore||(m._set("input",""),m._clear()),!1;m.files=e.get(0).files}if(l.uploadFile||l.addMore||m._reset(!0),e.prop("jFiler").files=m.files,!m._filesCheck()||null!=l.beforeSelect&&"function"==typeof l.beforeSelect&&!l.beforeSelect(m.files,i,g,h,e))return m._set("input",""),m._clear(),l.addMore&&j.length>0&&(m._unbindInput(!0),j[j.length-1].remove(),j.splice(j.length-1,1),e=j.length>0?j[j.length-1]:a(d),m._bindInput()),!1;if(m._set("feedback",m.files.length+m._itFl.length+" "+l.captions.feedback2),l.showThumbs)m._thumbCreator._box();else for(var f=0;f<m.files.length;f++)m.files[f]._choosed=!0,m._addToMemory(f),m._onSelect(f)},_append:function(a,b){var c=!!b&&b.files;if(c&&!(c.length<=0)&&(m.files=c,e.prop("jFiler").files=m.files,l.showThumbs)){for(var d=0;d<m.files.length;d++)m.files[d]._appended=!0;m._thumbCreator._box()}},_getList:function(a,b){var c=!!b&&b.files;if(c&&!(c.length<=0)&&(m.files=c,e.prop("jFiler").files=m.files,l.showThumbs)){for(var d=[],f=0;f<m.files.length;f++)m.files[f].forList=!0,d.push(m._thumbCreator.create(f));b.callback&&b.callback(d,i,g,h,e)}},_retryUpload:function(b,c){var d=parseInt("object"==typeof c?c.attr("data-jfiler-index"):c),f=m._itFl.filter(function(a,b){return a.id==d});return f.length>0&&(!l.uploadFile||a.isEmptyObject(l.uploadFile)||f[0].uploaded?void 0:(m._itFc=f[0],e.prop("jFiler").current_file=m._itFc,m._upload(d),!0))},_remove:function(b,d){if(d.binded){if("undefined"!=typeof d.data.id&&(d=i.find(l.templates._selectors.item+"[data-jfiler-index='"+d.data.id+"']"),0==d.length))return!1;d.data.el&&(d=d.data.el)}var f=function(b){var d=g.find("input[name^='jfiler-items-exclude-']:hidden").first();0==d.length&&(d=a('<input type="hidden" name="jfiler-items-exclude-'+(l.excludeName?l.excludeName:("[]"!=e.attr("name").slice(-2)?e.attr("name"):e.attr("name").substring(0,e.attr("name").length-2))+"-"+c)+'">'),d.appendTo(g)),b&&a.isArray(b)&&(b=JSON.stringify(b),d.val(b))},j=function(b,c){var d=m._itFl[c],e=[];if(d.file._choosed||d.file._appended||d.uploaded){m._itFr.push(d);for(var g=m._itFl.filter(function(a){return a.file.name==d.file.name}),h=0;h<m._itFr.length;h++)l.addMore&&m._itFr[h]==d&&g.length>0&&(m._itFr[h].remove_name=g.indexOf(d)+"://"+m._itFr[h].file.name),e.push(m._itFr[h].remove_name?m._itFr[h].remove_name:m._itFr[h].file.name)}f(e),m._itFl.splice(c,1),m._itFl.length<1?(m._reset(),m._clear()):m._set("feedback",m._itFl.length+" "+l.captions.feedback2),b.fadeOut("fast",function(){a(this).remove()})},k=d.get(0).jfiler_id||d.attr("data-jfiler-index"),n=null;for(var o in m._itFl)"length"!==o&&m._itFl.hasOwnProperty(o)&&m._itFl[o].id==k&&(n=o);return!!m._itFl.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(m._itFl[n].ajax?(m._itFl[n].ajax.abort(),void j(d,n)):void(null!=l.onRemove&&"function"==typeof l.onRemove&&l.onRemove(d,m._itFl[n].file,n,i,g,h,e)===!1||j(d,n)))},_addToMemory:function(b){m._itFl.push({id:m._itFl.length,file:m.files[b],html:a(),ajax:!1,uploaded:!1}),(l.addMore||m.files[b]._appended)&&(m._itFl[m._itFl.length-1].input=e),m._itFc=m._itFl[m._itFl.length-1],e.prop("jFiler").files_list=m._itFl,e.prop("jFiler").current_file=m._itFc},_assets:{bytesToSize:function(a){if(0==a)return"0 Byte";var b=1e3,c=["Bytes","KB","MB","GB","TB","PB","EB","ZB","YB"],d=Math.floor(Math.log(a)/Math.log(b));return(a/Math.pow(b,d)).toPrecision(3)+" "+c[d]},hasAttr:function(a,b){var b=b?b:e,c=b.attr(a);return!(!c||"undefined"==typeof c)},getIcon:function(b,c){var d=["audio","image","text","video"];return a.inArray(c,d)>-1?'<i class="icon-jfi-file-'+c+" jfi-file-ext-"+b+'"></i>':'<i class="icon-jfi-file-o jfi-file-type-'+c+" jfi-file-ext-"+b+'"></i>'},textParse:function(b,c){switch(c=a.extend({},{limit:l.limit,maxSize:l.maxSize,fileMaxSize:l.fileMaxSize,extensions:l.extensions?l.extensions.join(","):null},c&&a.isPlainObject(c)?c:{},l.options),typeof b){case"string":return b.replace(/\{\{fi-(.*?)\}\}/g,function(a,b){return b=b.replace(/ /g,""),b.match(/(.*?)\|limitTo\:(\d+)/)?b.replace(/(.*?)\|limitTo\:(\d+)/,function(a,b,d){var b=c[b]?c[b]:"",e=b.substring(0,d);return e=b.length>e.length?e.substring(0,e.length-3)+"...":e}):c[b]?c[b]:""});case"function":return b(c);default:return b}},text2Color:function(a){if(!a||0==a.length)return!1;for(var b=0,c=0;b<a.length;c=a.charCodeAt(b++)+((c<<5)-c));for(var b=0,d="#";b<3;d+=("00"+(c>>2*b++&255).toString(16)).slice(-2));return d}},files:null,_itFl:[],_itFc:null,_itFr:[],_itPl:[],_ajFc:0};return e.on("filer.append",function(a,b){m._append(a,b)}).on("filer.remove",function(a,b){b.binded=!0,m._remove(a,b)}).on("filer.reset",function(a){return m._reset(),m._clear(),!0}).on("filer.generateList",function(a,b){return m._getList(a,b)}).on("filer.retry",function(a,b){return m._retryUpload(a,b)}),m.init(),this})},a.fn.filer.defaults={limit:null,maxSize:null,fileMaxSize:null,extensions:null,changeInput:!0,showThumbs:!1,appendTo:null,theme:"default",templates:{box:'<ul class="jFiler-items-list jFiler-items-default"></ul>',item:'<li class="jFiler-item"><div class="jFiler-item-container"><div class="jFiler-item-inner"><div class="jFiler-item-icon pull-left">{{fi-icon}}</div><div class="jFiler-item-info pull-left"><div class="jFiler-item-title" title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name | limitTo:30}}</div><div class="jFiler-item-others"><span>size: {{fi-size2}}</span><span>type: {{fi-extension}}</span><span class="jFiler-item-status">{{fi-progressBar}}</span></div><div class="jFiler-item-assets"><ul class="list-inline"><li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></li>',itemAppend:'<li class="jFiler-item"><div class="jFiler-item-container"><div class="jFiler-item-inner"><div class="jFiler-item-icon pull-left">{{fi-icon}}</div><div class="jFiler-item-info pull-left"><div class="jFiler-item-title">{{fi-name | limitTo:35}}</div><div class="jFiler-item-others"><span>size: {{fi-size2}}</span><span>type: {{fi-extension}}</span><span class="jFiler-item-status"></span></div><div class="jFiler-item-assets"><ul class="list-inline"><li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></li>',progressBar:'<div class="bar"></div>',itemAppendToEnd:!1,removeConfirmation:!0,canvasImage:!0,_selectors:{list:".jFiler-items-list",item:".jFiler-item",progressBar:".bar",remove:".jFiler-item-trash-action"}},files:null,uploadFile:null,dragDrop:null,addMore:!1,allowDuplicates:!1,clipBoardPaste:!0,excludeName:null,beforeRender:null,afterRender:null,beforeShow:null,beforeSelect:null,onSelect:null,onFileCheck:null,afterShow:null,onRemove:null,onEmpty:null,options:null,dialogs:{alert:function(a){return alert(a)},confirm:function(a,b){confirm(a)?b():null}},captions:{button:"Choose Files",feedback:"Choose files To Upload",feedback2:"files were chosen",drop:"Drop file here to Upload",removeConfirmation:"Are you sure you want to remove this file?",errors:{filesLimit:"Only {{fi-limit}} files are allowed to be uploaded.",filesType:"Only Images are allowed to be uploaded.",filesSize:"{{fi-name}} is too large! Please upload file up to {{fi-fileMaxSize}} MB.",filesSizeAll:"Files you've choosed are too large! Please upload files up to {{fi-maxSize}} MB.",folderUpload:"You are not allowed to upload folders."}}}}(jQuery);

//start portfolio add and remove doc
    var max_fields3 = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper3 = $("#portfoliodocs"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button3 = $(".addmore_doc"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button3).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields3) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper3).append('<div class="form-group label-floating is-empty onerow portwidth2"><div class="socialmediaside2"><input type="text" class="form-control g" name="portfoliodoctitle[]" maxlength="10" value="" placeholder="Document Title"><div class="jFiler jFiler-theme-default"><input type="file" class="docupload" name="portfoliodoc[]" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; top: -9999px; z-index: -9999;"><div class="jFiler-input"><div class="jFiler-input-caption"><span>Choose files To Upload</span></div><div class="jFiler-input-button">Choose Files</div></div></div></div><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm bckbtn remove_field3"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true">-</i></button></div>'); //add input box  
         }
    }); 
    $(wrapper3).on("click", ".remove_field3", function (e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });
    //end portfolio add and remove doc

    $('.docupload').filer({
        limit: 5
        , maxSize: 2
        , fileMaxSize: 1
        , extensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif"]
        , showThumbs: true
        , addMore: true
        , allowDuplicates: false
        , canvasImage: true
        , templates: {
            box: '<ul class="jFiler-items-list jFiler-items-grid"></ul>'
            , item: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                        <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-thumb-overlay">\
                                        <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                            <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">\
                                                <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name}}</b></span>\
                                                <span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-size2}}</span>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>\
                                    </div>\
                                    {{fi-image}}\
                                </div>\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-left">\
                                        <li>{{fi-progressBar}}</li>\
                                    </ul>\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                        <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                                    </ul>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </li>'
            , itemAppend: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                                        <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                                        <div class="jFiler-item-thumb-overlay">\
                                            <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                                <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">\
                                                    <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name}}</b></span>\
                                                    <span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-size2}}</span>\
                                                </div>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>\
                                        {{fi-image}}\
                                    </div>\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                                        <ul class="list-inline pull-left">\
                                            <li><span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-icon}}</span></li>\
                                        </ul>\
                                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                            <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                                        </ul>\
                                    </div>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </li>'
            , progressBar: '<div class="bar"></div>'
            , itemAppendToEnd: false
            , canvasImage: true
            , removeConfirmation: true
            , _selectors: {
                list: '.jFiler-items-list'
                , item: '.jFiler-item'
                , progressBar: '.bar'
                , remove: '.jFiler-item-trash-action'
            }
        }
        , dialogs: {
            alert: function (text) {
                return alert(text);
            }
            , confirm: function (text, callback) {
                confirm(text) ? callback() : null;
            }
        }
        , captions: {
            button: "Choose Files"
            , feedback: "Choose files To Upload"
            , feedback2: "files were chosen"
            , drop: "Drop file here to Upload"
            , removeConfirmation: "Are you sure you want to remove this file?"
            , errors: {
                filesLimit: "Only {{fi-limit}} files are allowed to be uploaded."
                , filesType: "Only Images are allowed to be uploaded."
                , filesSize: "{{fi-name}} is too large! Please upload file up to {{fi-maxSize}} MB."
                , filesSizeAll: "Files you've choosed are too large! Please upload files up to {{fi-maxSize}} MB."
            }
        }
    }); 

    }
</script>

    <script src="https://gerardbalaoro.github.io/jQuery.filer/js/scripts/prettify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: create a jsfiddle

Comment: @DhananjaiPai please check the update jsFiddle has been added